# Get syntax error when trying to import amCharts modules

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, amcharts

i am trying to use amcharts through npm, i run the command npm install@amcharts/amcharts4 in the i can see that now in my node modules and in my package.json i have all the modules associated with the amcharts, also my package.json got updated and now inludes this line "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.22", i have created two files an index.html and a charts.js. At the top of my app.js i added the following lines

```
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
```

when i try to include my charts.hs in my index.html with the following script

```
<script src="charts.js"></script>
```

i get the same syntax error all the time and i still cant find a way to resolve it
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
"
does anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried googling for that error message? It's pretty clear: the browser does not consider your `<script>` to be a module, and therefore `import` is not allowed.

Comment: Yes i did the best answer i found it was to change my script to <script src="charts.js " type="module"></script>

Comment: when i do though i get a different error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@amcharts/amcharts4/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
"

Answer (score 0):

try :
npm install @amcharts/amcharts4 -force

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!